# Cannot retrieve FormsAuthentication cookie when working in load balanced environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, load-balancing

We are implementing the load balancer with 3 Servers. Suppose a situation like this. User logs into the system from Server1 and the Server1 responses with the authentication cookie. if any consecutive request from that (authenticated) user is made on Server1 everything fine, but if the request is made on Server2 or Server3 than the problem occures. Basically the cookie is presend in `HTTP headers` but when retrieving it in `Global.asax`'s `Application_AuthenticateRequest` with the following code

```
var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

it comes out to be `null`. I think that there should be a problem with the ticket itself which is present in authentication cookie. The ticket is not valid for some reason. As I searcher the web I found out that the MachineKey is used to Encrypt and Decrypt (am I right ? this is my guess) the ticket, and the different machines are having the different MachineKey. Can I share the MachineKey between the servers ? Would I be exposed to any kind of vulnurability that way ? What is the best workaround in this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem with load balanced environments. To resolved the issue you have to specify a machine key on web.config file. All the web.config files on load balanced servers need to have the same machine key.

An example of machine key specification is below

```
<machineKey 
    validationKey="35E679E7C03505829CDAEA7C14C6EEEBFA8A786E2F10FB24921ECC1965AA1B18B1794234DF4DD4247CA57119CB0CF806BFCED445C303A22E8C5D33D381F6A37ABFD5" 
    decryptionKey="20FD16825FC53SFASDRWERSF5565656F5E5A5F47A49114CD2E1DE8EE70A853BFAE7E3D1F0" 
    validation="SHA1" 
    decryption="AES" />
```

[Read more about machine key.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)

As you have said that machine key values are used to encrypt and decrypt the authentication cookie. If this values are not explicitly specified on the servers they will generate their own. Now the decryption key for server 1 will not be same on server 2, hence the decryption fails. If you specify the keys explicitly on each server then all of them will use same keys to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Great. That's exactly what I was looking for.